# How to run mongorestore after mongod in docker

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a mongodb-server with docker, let it download a dump from the web and populate it with that info. My problem is that I can make it run and fill the database, but after it's done that, it just closes.

This was how I went about solving my problem:

`sudo -u mongodb /usr/bin/mongod --config $conf $args &
mongorestore dump`

The problem here is that I can't run *mongorestore* if *mongod* isn't running, but if I start mongod with `mongod &`, then the container will close down after *mongorestore* has finished running.

In my *Dockerfile*, I'm running those commands by doing
`CMD ["/etc/mongod/mongostart.sh"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your mongod container

```
docker run -d --name mymongod ... mongo ...
```

Start a 2nd container for mongorestore, linking it to the first:

```
docker run --link mymongod:db ... mongo mongorestore -h db ...
```

`mongorestore` will connect to the `mymongod` container via the alias `db` that docker creates based on the specified `--link`