# How can I run mongorestore from my Dockerfile?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to set up a test mongo database in a docker container by having `RUN mongorestore --archive=archivefile` in the Dockerfile.

The whole `testdb.Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM mongo

COPY archivefile /
WORKDIR / 
RUN mongorestore --archive='./archivefile'
```

Which should run the command and test up the database from my backup. However, I get this as a result.

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: Single
Servers:
Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(localhost:27017[-121]) connection is closed
```

I looked up, and it turns out I need to run `mongod` first, so I changed my dockerfile to

```
FROM mongo

COPY archivefile /
WORKDIR / 
RUN mongod &
RUN mongorestore --archive='./archivefile'
```

No luck, same thing happens. I even tried to add a `sleep` command to completely wait for mongod to be set up.

I also tried this [How to run mongorestore after mongod in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118159/how-to-run-mongorestore-after-mongod-in-docker)
But I had the same issue.

For reference, this is my minimal `docker-compose` file

```
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: testdb.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  app:
    # other stuff
    links: 
      - mongo
```

I would prefer just these two containers to be talking to each other, but I don't mind adding a third.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore DB during docker build time in your both approach and your first approach mongo DB services are not started at all and the second approach each run command run in a separate shell, plus the Docker image attached volume so you all you need below.

```
FROM mongo
COPY initdb.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions `.sh and .js` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. `.js` files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the `.js script`.

[Initializing a fresh instance with DB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

Comment: This worked well.
I created a sh script that just contains `mongorestore --archive='/archivefile'`.
Then my dockerfile contains `COPY scripts/mongorestore.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`